# Get value in csv file in same row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

So given a csv file as a dataframe using pandas and python, i'd like to get the value which is in the same row as another value **as efficiently as possible**.

To clarify this, i will give you an example with the following csv:

```
STAID   SOUID   DATE      TX     Q_TX
162     100522  19010101 -31     0
162     100522  19010102 -13     0
162     100522  19010103 -5      0
162     100522  19010104 -10     0
162     100522  19010105 -18     0
```

So lets say im implementing te following code

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("foo.csv")

max_val = data["TX"].max()
```

Max_val will now get a value of -5. The thing is that I would now like to know the value in 'DATE' which will be in the same row as max_val, or in other words: a value in the column 'DATE' sharing the same index as the found value. The desired value that I'm aiming for is 19010103. What is the most efficient way to do this only using pandas??

UPDATE: Derped a bit with the min_val, it should obviously be max_val instead of min_val.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `loc` is the "standard" and should be highly readable. but using `idxmax` with `at` is your FASTEST answer here (SEE Wen's Answer for where i got the idea). You may want to test with your real data to ensure this small amount of data isn't providing red herrings. See [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

> Fast label-based scalar accessor
>   Similarly to loc, at provides label based scalar lookups. You can also set using these indexers.

Fastest answer here from my testing:

```
min_val = data.TX.idxmax() #with min_val's index already set
%%timeit
data.at[min_val,'DATE']
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.73 µs per loop
```

using `%%timeit` on jupyter you can see the time:

```
%%timeit
data.loc[data['TX'] == min_val]['DATE']
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 604 µs per loop

%%timeit
data[data['TX']==min_val)].DATE #using from comments, and not using loc
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 724 µs per loop

%%timeit
data[data['TX']==data['TX'].max()]['DATE']
#1000 loops, best of 3: 575 µs per loop 

%%timeit
data.at[data.TX.idxmax(),'DATE'] #using at and idxmax <----
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 69.5 µs per loop

%%timeit
data.at[data.loc[data['TX'] == min_val].index[0],'DATE']
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 560 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thx alot! even though the idxmax solution is more straightforward I prefer your solution since its much more generic

Comment: This seems very similar to microsoft excel's VLOOKUP function. How does this python functionality handle multiple rows which match the lookup criteria? For example if 3 rows each contained -5

Answer (score 5):

We can using `idxmax`

```
df.DATE[df.TX.idxmax()]
Out[346]: 19010103
```

For enhance the speed

```
df.values[2,df.TX.values.argmax()]
```

Comment: `10000 loops, best of 3: 77.6 µs per loop` WOW!! that's quick. May be trivial but `data['DATE'][data['TX'].idxmax()]`  returns `10000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 µs per loop`

Comment: I really enjoyed your answer. I incorporated it using `at` in my testing to get the fastest result.

Comment: @MattR aha, using `at` should be fast :-)

Comment: @MattR you can check the numpy approach even faster than idxmax .

Comment: That is interesting... numpy is (marginally) slower. Did you have a different idea in mind?`min_val = np.argmax(data['TX']) # 10000 loops, best of 3: 51 µs per loop` versus `min_val = data.TX.idxmax() # 10000 loops, best of 3: 48.7 µs per loop`

Comment: @MattR test this one np.argmax(data['TX'].values)

Comment: `15.7 µs per loop`. This may be the fastest answer if `min_val` is not already defined!

Comment: Thanks alot! thats indeed a very good option, but this method is really good for minimum and maximum values in a dataframe, but cant be used for other values, right?

Comment: @WillemvanderSpek what others value you want ? you can look at numpy , they have plenty of function , should cover all

Comment: @WillemvanderSpek btw, if those answers help you out , you can upvote them

Comment: @Wen Lets say i randomly generate a number which is present in my column and non-unique. How would i get to the other column for the value that has the same index as my random number?

Comment: @WillemvanderSpek it is no clear to me can you add some example?